# MS Word - Mail merge show multiple records per page if key field is the same

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to set a mail merge document with the data below. I am trying to populate multiple records in the same page if the customer no is equal.

Example:

| Customer No | Name | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Alan | 555555 |
| 1234 | Alan | 666666 |
| 5678 | Jim | 777777 |
| 7896 | Morrison | 888888 |

Assuming I have the above excel file (as the source file) containing the above data I want the mail merge to show the following:

Page 1:
Dear Bla Bla Bla.....

| Customer No | Name | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Alan | 555555 |
| 1234 | Alan | 666666 |

Page2:
Dear Bla Bla Bla.....

| Customer No | Name | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | Jim | 777777 |

Page3:
Dear Bla Bla Bla.....

| Customer No | Name | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7896 | Morrison | 888888 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Microsoft link, there are too many steps to document
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-directory-of-names-addresses-and-other-information-49afe95c-dc99-4cd3-85c7-3a80869cff90

Sorry, this might work. I'm just board on my phone so can't test:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-nextif-field-5dd7bd9c-29b1-4ef2-aba8-4f0387e8b417

Comment: Thank you for the link provided however the process described in the link is a normal mail merge. I would like to achieve the mail merge to include two rows in one page if the customer number is equal.

Comment: Sorry, added another one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Furthermore, please note that i also found interesting when setting my mail merge up. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIfid43hlHw